# Como pegar um objeto filho usando Axios?

Tags: javascript, react, front-end, get, axios

Estou fazendo um site utilizando React. Quando executo o método GET, obtenho o seguinte resultado
[image: banco de dados:]

No frontend, o código está assim:

```js
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class ListaTarefas extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tarefas: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3004/api/listaTarefas/')
      .then(res => {
        const tarefas = res.data
        console.log(res.data)
        this.setState({ tarefas })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.tarefas.map(tarefa => 
        <li key={tarefa._id}> {tarefa.nomeTarefa} </li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Eu consigo pegar normalmente o nomeTarefa, completas, etc, mas gostaria de saber como faço para pegar o atributo nomeSub, que possui outros atributos.

Comment: se fez errado na linha `const tarefas = res.data` na verdade é `const { tarefas } = res.data;` isso já resolve, tem o nome certinho, mas, não lembro agora são tantos nomes

Comment: cara, tentei isso e não aparecem mais os resultados, começou a dar erro no tarefas.map também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tarefa.subTarefa.nomeSub ou tarefa.subTarefa[0].nomeSub

Comment: obrigado, resolveu!